# Hibernate: How to update on different ID

Tags: hibernate, entity

**Question:** How do I indicate in Hibernate that the [ref] is the true primary key but when updating the record I want it to apply .update or .saveOrUpdate on the [objectID].

**Context:** I have a scenario where I'm synchronising information from a webservice into a table. On importing an object I retain the objects unique reference, this enables me to run the script again and update the objects information which is held locally.

Example: A simple table consisting of three fields.

[ref] [objectID] [objectTitle]

[ref] = A primary key. Increments on a new record insert. Used for internal lookups and relationship associations.

[objectID] = The unique identifier of the object itself.

[objectTitle] = The information tied to the objectID. This may change on an update.

I'm a bit confused on how to set this up within Hibernate. It would seem I **have** to set the [ref] as @Id so it will be auto-incremented using a generator. The problem is I want the information to be updated using the [objectID], not [ref].

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's quite simple.

You start by loading the entity which has the given objectID:

```
MyEntity m = 
    (MyEntity) session.createQuery("select m from MyEntity m where m.objectID = :objectID")
                      .setParameter("objectID", theObjectID)
                      .uniqueResult();
```

And then you update this entity with the new title you got from the web service:

```
m.setObjectTitle(theObjectTitle);
```

Comment: Is there a more efficient way of doing this? If you are synching 5,000+ records that's quite a big overhead to do for each one. Is there not a way I can indicate at the point of update which field to use as the reference key?

Comment: Yes, there is. Use an update query. But this leads to code that looks much more like JDBC code than with Hibernate code, probably won't be much more efficient (and could even be less efficient in some cases), and is more limiting. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct

Comment: You can of course also load many entities at once using a `where m.objectId in :listOfObjectIds` clause, if you need to modify many entities at once.

Answer (score -1):

Is this possible to update the 'id' column in the table; 
Where the 'id' in .hbm file is like:

```
<id name="id" type="int" column="id">
<generator class="increment"/>
</id>
```